# Defining php code as a variable - what is the simplest way?

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that will set an HTML code as variable like this:

```
public function get_code() {
    $code = '<h1>Title</h1>';
    $code .= '<p>Text</p>';
    return $code;
}
```

Now what if the HTML code was PHP code? Would it be possible to set PHP code as a variable?

I understand that the PHP code needs to be a string. So this is one way how to do it:

```
public function get_code() {
    $code = '
                if (in_array(\'custom_less\', $options)) {
                    $style = \'@import "assets/css/style.less"\';
                }
    ';
    return $code;
}
```

Since I have a very large code, it is very annoying to go through each `'` and set a `\` before it in order to define the whole code as a string. Is there a way I could get rid of those backslashes?

The reason why I want it as a variable is because the code needs to be written in a file.

Comment: You could use [`nowdoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). I do need to ask, though, why do you need to put PHP-code in a variable? Unless it is for presentation (printing the actual code on a website or similar), it sounds like a code smell.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson. I think this must be what I am looking for. I need the PHP code as a variable since I want to write it to a file.

Comment: Can't you just store it in a file to start with?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nope, the code is getting generated dynamically based on users behavior.

Comment: `eval` has been introduced for such purpose

Comment: usually you have the code organised in functions, classes etc and follow a path through that based on user input, not generate code for every user

Comment: Hi @Reza, But the file that you'll write will be physically saved in the machine of the user? Or you're trying to generate a php page that will be executed after the generation?

Comment: @giovaZ the file will be created on the webserver, then the user will be able to download it. The php code will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use single quotation  inside double quotation and vice versa. so you can say like this.

```
public function get_code() {

        $code = "
            if (in_array('custom_less', $options)) {
                $style = '@import assets/css/style.less';
            }
        ";
        return $code;
}
```

Comment: So if my code also includes double quotations, I still have to go trough each single one and set a backslash before them. I am looking for a way to completely get rid of those backslashes.

Comment: then try using htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() functions

Comment: @AbdulAhad - Those methods would change the actual content, making it invalid if he wants to use it later on.

Comment: I thought he is going to save only

Answer (score 0):

If your want to store Pure HTML code in variable then simplest ways is

```
public function get_code() {
    $output = <<<EOD
<div>SOME HTML</div>
EOD;
return $output;
}
```

It's called heredoc syntax in PHP.